# How does Xcode generate the values for id attributes inside storyboard files?

Tags: ios, xcode, storyboard

For example, this is some code from a `.storyboard` file.

```
<scene sceneID="iia-3d-rxc">
    <objects>
        <viewController id="diG-vY-mTj" sceneMemberID="viewController">
            <layoutGuides>
                <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="top" id="doE-rD-hZg"/>
                <viewControllerLayoutGuide type="bottom" id="a3z-Fu-YSa"/>
            </layoutGuides>
            <view key="view" contentMode="scaleToFill" id="osR-Fj-lTh">
            <!-- ... -->
            </view>
        </viewController>
        <placeholder placeholderIdentifier="IBFirstResponder" id="ywT-Gm-hlb" userLabel="First Responder" sceneMemberID="firstResponder"/>
    </objects>
    <point key="canvasLocation" x="736" y="439"/>
</scene>
```

Every single node has an `id` attribute of the format `***-**-***`, where the stars are substituted with alphanumeric symbols.

What sort of format is this? What's the purpose of those `id` attributes and how are they generated?

Answer (score 1):

I have a hard time believing that these identities are randomly generated, since it would require unnecessary lookup tables during compilation.
Take, for example the identity "orR-Rm-srM".  It appears to be a base-62 number with each digit being a-zA-Z0-9. Giving us 8 62-value "bits".

Tom

Answer (score 0):

Everything I've seen says they're basically random.

Comment: What's important is not their randomness but their uniqueness. They are IDs.